# dired not showing recently created files when emacs is run in daemon mode

Tags: dired, auto-revert-mode, revert-buffer, global-auto-revert-mode

When running emacs in daemon mode, a directory listing using dired does not seem to show the latest created files.

What could be the cause of this issue, and how can I fix it?

Comment: `dired` does not automatically update directory buffers that are already open.  You can `revert-buffer` them, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Dan pointed out, by default you need to manually revert dired buffers (e.g., by typing `g`) in order to update the directory listing view.

If you want this to happen automatically, then you can turn on [auto-revert mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Autorevert.html). For example,

```
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook #'(turn-on-auto-revert-mode))
```

But see the Emacs manual, node [Auto Reverting Dired](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Reverting-Dired.html) for some limitations of this.

You might also want to combine that with something like this:

```el
(customize-set-value
  'auto-revert-verbose
  nil
  "Prevent any auto-revert messages from obscuring the minibuffer at crucial times!")
```